# Test manager, changed a shared step and all tests want to be re-recorded

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

In microsoft test manager, I have changed a shared step and now all the test cases that used that shared step have the message "The action recording cannot be loaded for..." which basically happens if you modify a step in the test case. Is there a work-around so I don't have to re-record all the steps(I only changed the shared step)?

Comment: Get me some **Screenshots** and i'll have a look

Comment: Screenshot of the error message? It's pretty generic but here it is:http://s8.postimg.org/55ognrkhx/Error.png

Comment: **dont use action recordings**

Comment: I wouldn't use the software at all, but it's required.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. In the future it is always best practice to record action recordings for shared steps separate from the action recording for the test case that uses them. You can record an action recording for just the shared step under the Organize > Shared Steps Manager tab.

Comment: Well, basically that's what I did. Then the shared step needed to be changed... Which is something that should be supported by test manager.(without re-recording all the test cases of course